# How to set timeout for Orchestration if there are more than one ActivityTrigger in Azure Durable function

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

In Orchestration, I need to set timeout at 30sec so after timeout, it should end/exit.

Or is there any way that we can set timeout to this `WaitForInstanceCompletionAsync()`?

```
[Function("TimerTrigger_EveryMinute")]
public async Task TimerTrigger_EveryMinute(
[TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")] TimerInfo timerInfo,
[DurableClient] DurableTaskClient starter)
{
 _logger.LogError($"Running timer trigger");

 string instanceId = await starter.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync("ORCHESTRATOR_TRIGGER_NAME");
 await starter.WaitForInstanceCompletionAsync(instanceId);

 _logger.LogInformation($"Completed orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'");
}


[Function("ORCHESTRATOR_TRIGGER_NAME")]
public async Task Run(
  [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
{
 var parallelTasks = new List<Task<int>>();

 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
     Task<int> task = context.CallActivityAsync<int>("getdata", i);
     parallelTasks.Add(task);
 }

 await Task.WhenAll(parallelTasks);
}
```

Comment: Use CancellationTokenSource  that creates CancellationToken for WaitForInstanceCompletionAsync. With CancellationTokenSource   use CancelAfter(30000);

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **@D A** on using **WaitForInstanceCompletionAsync**.

I tried the below Durable Functions Orchestration code to set a **timeout for 30 seconds.**

**Code** :

***TimerTriggerFunctions*** :

```cs
[FunctionName("TimerTrigger_EveryMinute")]
        public static async Task TimerTrigger_EveryMinute(
            [TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")] TimerInfo timerInfo,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient client,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogError("Running timer trigger");

            string instanceId = await client.StartNewAsync("ORCHESTRATOR_TRIGGER_NAME");

            var timeoutDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeoutDuration);

            var orchestrationStatus = await client.GetStatusAsync(instanceId);

            while (!orchestrationStatus.RuntimeStatus.HasFlag(OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Completed))
            {
                if (timeoutTask.IsCompleted)
                {
                    log.LogError("WaitForInstanceCompletionAsync timed out.");
                    break;
                }

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); 
                orchestrationStatus = await client.GetStatusAsync(instanceId);
            }

            log.LogInformation($"WaitForInstanceCompletionAsync completed for instance ID: {instanceId}");
        }
```

***OrchestrationFunctions*** :

```cs
[FunctionName("ORCHESTRATOR_TRIGGER_NAME")]
        public static async Task RunOrchestration(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var parallelTasks = new List<Task<int>>();

            for (int p = 0; p < 5; p++)
            {
                Task<int> task = context.CallActivityAsync<int>("getdata", p);
                parallelTasks.Add(task);
            }
            var timeoutDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            var timeoutTask = context.CreateTimer(context.CurrentUtcDateTime.Add(timeoutDuration), CancellationToken.None);

            var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(parallelTasks), timeoutTask);

            if (completedTask == timeoutTask)
            {
                log.LogError("Orchestration timed out.");
            }
            else
            {
                log.LogInformation("Orchestration completed successfully.");
            }
        }
```

**Output** :

[image]

Comment: How to know which ParallelTasks are executed and which ParallelTasks are timeout. 

Am using [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context not  [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context.

Comment: @Shashimk You can maintain a list of completed tasks within your orchestration and check their status to determine which ones executed and which ones timed out.

Comment: I am using   [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context not [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context.